# Which user Git will use for SSH authentication

Tags: git, ssh

When having a Git repository with a `git@bitbucket.org/project` remote and the `~/.ssh/config` file has (among others) following entry:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    User tom
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket.rsa
```

Which user has precedence over the other (e.g. when invoking a `fetch`)?

Comment: You specified the user with the `git@` part in the URL, so the configuration for `tom` will not be used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which user has precedence over the other (e.g. when invoking a fetch)?

This is described in the manual page for `ssh_config`:

> `ssh(1)` obtains configuration data from the following sources in the following order:
>
> 1. command-line options
> 2. user's configuration file (`~/.ssh/config`)
> 3. system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`)

This means that the command-line (git remote `git`) will be used.

Comment: Note that those do not refer to the user name but only the general configuration. Git always requires you to specify a user name with SSH remote urls, so that’s always what counts. `ssh` will then just look at those places to find a possible configuration for that `user@host` combination.

Comment: @poke Thanks. Good point. But it does not change the thing that user `git` will be used.

Comment: That’s right; but it will not take that user because of the reasons you outlined.

Comment: Problem: I'm writing an SSH client that gets the user name from Git and has to manage the `.ssh/config`. If the remote URL is `git@bitbucket.org/project`, Git passes the user "git", but if the URL is without the user, Git passes the system user "tom". That way I can't distinguish between with and without user in the URL and hence don't have an option to take the user from the `.git/config`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an host file like in your question the host file will load the ssh keys and will "skip reading" (not really just for making it clear) the `.ssh` folder

In your case , this files will set the default configuration for all users on the system based upon their key.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the "hosts" file nor how the ~/.ssh/config should have influence to all users.